# Navigation drawer does not automatically start the recyclerview fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

I had a fully functional recycler view that opens as a fragment of a Navigation drawer when the app opens to it. I changed some code and inadvertently misplaced some code and now when the navigation drawer opens, the fragment is blank until I click on the fragment to open again in the drawer does it display the recyclerview and it's contents. Can I get some help determining the piece of code missing?

I haven't touch this piece of code in a while because I thought It was running fine, so I can't visualize the code anymore but I went through the tutorials I used for the navigation drawer and the recyclerview to make sure they would work individually, and it looks like I have it all. I check some questions on Stack overflow but they seem to only correspond to firebase recyclerview and don't really answer my particular issue.

This page is where the drawer is initialized and the recyclerview should be called.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.front_page);
        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_front_page);
        NavigationView nV = findViewById(R.id.drawer_view);
        View header = nV.getHeaderView(0);
        nV.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
        toggle.syncState();
        nV.setCheckedItem(R.id.list_venue);

        /*ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)

                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

         if(!networkInfo.isConnected()){

         }*/
        //TODO: Create network status check with animation and Dialog
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        isLoggedOut = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGINSTATUS,false);
        drawerProfilePicture = header.findViewById(R.id.drawer_pic_profile);
        drawerUserName = header.findViewById(R.id.drawer_profile_username);
        drawerUserEmail = header.findViewById(R.id.drawer_profile_email);

        if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && !AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().isExpired()) {
            facebookLogin();
        } else {
            inHouseSignUp();
        }
    }
```

And here is the `recyclerview`

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_venue, container, false);

        if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
            Places.initialize(contextForPlaces, "AIzaSyCKGd3fqmtsDklRGMhnkuIy1GS-j6gRBh8");
        }
        RecyclerView vRV = view.findViewById(R.id.view_venue);
        vRV.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager vLM = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
        vAdapter = new VenueAdapter(vIL);
        vAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this::shareTheView);

        placesClient = Places.createClient(contextForPlaces);


        //TODO: Make App mention when there is no service
        //TODO Figure out animation for scrolling
        //TODO: add code to make sure that the VenueList is complete before displaying it
        //look for transfering keys for the information instead of the information itself

        //TODO: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout


        for (String club : clubs) {
            FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(club, placeFields);
            placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
                Place place = response.getPlace();
                PhotoMetadata photoMetadata = Objects.requireNonNull(place.getPhotoMetadatas()).get(0);
                //String attributions = photoMetadata.getAttributions();

                FetchPhotoRequest photoRequest = FetchPhotoRequest.builder(photoMetadata).setMaxHeight(400).setMaxWidth(400).build();
                placesClient.fetchPhoto(photoRequest).addOnSuccessListener((fetchPhotoResponse) -> {

                    Bitmap bitmap = fetchPhotoResponse.getBitmap();

                    vIL.add(new VenueItem( /*Photo*/bitmap, place.getName()));

                    //Log.i(TAG, "Photo Should Be Up");
                    vRV.setLayoutManager(vLM);
                    vRV.setAdapter(vAdapter);
                }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
                    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                        int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                        // Handle error with given status code.
                        Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + place.getName());
            }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
                if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                    ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                    int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                    // Handle error with given status code.
                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
        vAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return view;
    }
```

All the code works but it won't open when it is first called and I need to manually call it, which never happened before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after for loop

```
for(String club : clubs){}
vAdapter = new VenueAdapter(vIL);
vRV.setLayoutManager(vLM);
vRV.setAdapter(vAdapter);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work because the recyclerview needs to be accessed every iteration since it's supposed to be final for the google api. (I may have got the reason wrong but the code for the adapter needs to be there.) I figured it out, that you for your help. I got overzealous cleaning up some code and I erased a few lines that dictated which fragment to start with at launch

Answer (score 0):

I found the code I erased.This piece of code dictates which Fragment starts at launch if there isn't one availiable

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new VenueList()).commit();
        nV.setCheckedItem(R.id.list_venue);
    }
```